# Artifactory on debian: how to update from zip install to aptitude install?

Tags: debian, artifactory

A few months ago I installed Artifactory oss (open source) 5.0 on debian (*jessie*, then upgraded to *stretch*) from a zip file, and let it live its life unattended (now “happily serving 13,060 artefacts”).

Today I realize that I am somewhat lagging versionwise (Artifactory is currently at version 5.4.6) and I want to upgrade it.

I found out there is a debian repository, and I dearly wish, from now on, to go by *apt-get upgrade* routinely on Artifactory.

Is it possible ?

The question is **“How do I migrate from a zip manual install of Artifactory 5.0 to an *aptitude* install?”**

Thanks.

edit : the artifactory debian repository doesn’t know *stretch* yet, only *jessie*. Would that be a problem?

```
deb https://jfrog.bintray.com/artifactory-debs jessie main
```

Answer (score 0):

similar issue for me.

I've decided to define 'xenial' cause it should be similar to 'stretch'. So far, I successfully installed the package and run the jfrog oss smoothly.

```
deb https://jfrog.bintray.com/artifactory-debs xenial main
```

You will probably encounter one more issue about mariadb instead of mysql. Here is a quick fix :

```
sed -i 's/^MYSQL_MIN_VERSION=.*/MYSQL_MIN_VERSION=10.1.26/' /opt/jfrog/artifactory/bin/configure.mysql.sh
```

Comment: Thank you, but it is only a very small part of my question, which is “how to migrate from a zip install to an apt-get install of artifactory?”

Comment: yes, you're right.
you should visit the page : 
https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Installing+on+Linux+Solaris+or+Mac+OS
there are installation instructions. (not tested)

Comment: Thanks, that page – which I visited before – explains how to install from zip, and also how to install from apt-get. My question is “how to migrate from one install to the other”. The reply may well be that it is not feasible, that I’d have to backup, uninstall, install from scratch, import. Would that work?